# Given a Relation (set of ordered pairs), prove transitivity without going through each pair?

Tags: relations

Give a relation, R, on the set of integers, such as R = {(1,2)(2,2) ...  } is there a way to determine transitivity without going through each ordered pair (x,y)(y,z) to see if (x,z) is there?

Comment: If you are given some rule for the pairs in $R$, maybe.  If it is just a list (which is a fine way to specify a relation), no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. you have to check for each pair of ordered pair. Sorry no shortcuts